# Writing "NfcA only" tags with Android

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, mifare

I've few NFC tags wich have only `android.nfc.tech.NfcA` in `Tech list`. I've tried to write data on it using [this](https://shanetully.com/2012/12/writing-custom-data-to-nfc-tags-with-android-example/) example, but I've failed, as I understood tag should support `NdefFormatable` in order to be written in this way. [NFC TagWriter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter) also can't write this tags. 
 
**My question is:** Is it possible to write such tags in Android? If yes how can I do this?

**Update** 
According to sellers information this tags based on `Mifare 1K S50` chip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tag is MIFARE Classic 1K (that's the type you indicate in your update) and your phone does not support MIFARE Classic (i.e. tech-list does not report MifareClassic technology, which means that your device has a non-NXP NFC chipset, e.g. Nexus 4, Nexus 5, etc.) then you are out of luck. There is no way to read or write those tags if the NFC chipset does not have a MIFARE Classic reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It really seems that I've faced "Mifare Classic NFC Tags 
Compatibility Issues With Nexus 4". For the future seekers: this problem described in details here http://www.andytags.com/nfc-tags-compatibility-issues.html#.UqSGBuKinSc